# How to add identical integers in a list together?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Stuck on part of function for school which requires me to add all identical integers in a list and return the total. For example given the list `[2,3,3]` I want `6` to be returned or given a list like `[5,6,5]`, I would like `10` to be returned. Sine I am going to be using this as part of an if-statement, what's the shortest way to do this?

I've tried using indexing but I can't figure out how to get the if-statement to realize which combination of elements are the same so they can be added together and returned.

NOTE: The length of the list will never be more than 3 and I already have the case covered in which all 3 elements are the same. It's just with the combination of two elements which I'm having trouble with.

Comment: share what you tried

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: maybe create dictionary in which you will count how many  times numbers exists on list - or use `collections.Counter` for this. `if number not in counter: counter[number] = 1 else: counter[number] += 1`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a ladder if `if`/`elif` statements:

```
if lst[0] == lst[1] == lst[2]:
    return 3 * lst[0]
elif lst[0] == lst[1] or lst[0] == lst[2]
    return 2 * lst[0]
elif lst[1] == lst[2]
    return 2 * lst[1]
else:
    return None # no duplicates
```

Or if you expect more related cases later (e.g. longer lists), you could generalize this to "return the sum of the most common item in the list". The easiest way to do that is probably to use one loop to create a `dict` with the number of occurrences of each unique value, then another loop through that to find the most common item `x` and its count `n`, then return `x * n`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code covers all three situations and can be used within function:

```
#z=[3,4,5]
z=[3,4,4]
#z=[7,7,7]
y = [0,0]
y = y + z
print(y)
for x in set(y):
    y.remove(x)
b = y[-1]*len(y)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works with lists up to length 3 (i.e. 0, 1, 2, or 3)

```
def sum_dup(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0):
  """ Using defaults allows strategy to Works with lists of length 0, 1, 2, or 3.  
      If we have fewer than three inputs then missing inputs are 0 by default """
  if a == b == c:
    # all three are equal
    return a + b + c
  elif a == b:
    # equal first & second
    return a + b
  elif b == c:
    # second & third
    return b + c
  elif a == c:
    # first & third
    return a + c
  else:
    # none are equal
    return 0
```

**Test Lists**

```
lsts = [[5], [5, 5, 5], [], [0, 5], [2, 3, 3], [5, 0, 5]]

for lst in lsts:
  # *lst explands list into input for sum_dup
  # meaning same as sum_dup(lst[0], lst[1], etc.)
  print(f'List {lst} has sum {sum_dup(*lst)}')
```

**Output**

```
List [5] has sum 0
List [5, 5, 5] has sum 15
List [] has sum 0
List [0, 5] has sum 0
List [2, 3, 3] has sum 6
List [5, 0, 5] has sum 10
```

Answer (score -1):

The crux of the problem is determining which values (a, b, and c) are, in fact, duplicates. Given this, could we somehow keep track of what we know is a dup? If we start by assuming no dups, can we check the possible combinations that would showcase which vals **are** dups? If we know which combinations prove which values are dups and can update the trackers mentioned in the second sentence, we should be able to add the respective parameters and achieve our final result.

If this is too cryptic, let me know and I can try to elaborate, but try parsing the above and see if you can turn it into something that works.